# Error:Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1

Tags: android

I have install android studio on macbook pro and I am sure I have install all the required SDK for it to work but yet still I am having issues with errors. below is the error messages

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>   Required by: project :app
>
> No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1 available for offline mode.

here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.air.my1st"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Add `google()` to both `repositories` closures in your project's `build.gradle` file. Then, switch your `26.0.0-beta1` dependencies to `26.1.0`.

Comment: I already have google() in both repositories already @CommonsWare

Comment: thanks after switching 26.0.0-beta1 dependencies to 26.1.0 it works fine... thanks bro @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

add this code in build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
        maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Consider explain why these lines fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `targetSdkVersion` 27

Dependencies to latest:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`